# Galaxy S4 Video Recording: File Size Limit & Frequent Blurring

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, samsung-galaxy-s-4, video-recording, ntfs

I'm trying to use Galaxy S4 as a video camera for recording offline usergroups. Apart from whether it's a good idea, it's generally succeeding, but there are some critical problems:

- Android file system does not support files larger than 4GB. At 1280x720 resolution, this is about 40-something minutes, which is sometimes less than what I typically need (some sessions take 60+ minutes), which causes a sudden video stop, and if I'm conscious enough, I press the recording again, and lose about a minute or less in between.

  I'm thinking this problem might be solved by rooting the phone and buying one of the programs that allow mounting NTFS for Android, formatting an SD card as NTFS as well. Would you expect this to work? Any luck with any of this programs and recording to memory card?
- Sometimes the phone blurs the text it records and afterwards the text becomes clear again. Sometimes this happens quite often that it becomes annoying to anyone watching the video. I have tried disabling video stabilization but this doesn't seem to improve it much. It still insists on blurring text at random times. It probably is trying to help me with some autofocus thing, but it's only doing harm.

  I'm short of ideas for this one. Anyone managed to stop it?

Not sure if this should be split into 2 questions, but would appreciate help on either anyway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (so it's a comment, not an answer, simply giving thoughts), but AFAIK the file size limitation is not only on the file system, but generally kept by Android. So a solution would be a camera which automatically splits a running recording into multiple files, say at e.g. 2 GB, and continues recording. Additionally, it should permit you to turn off auto-focus (you've guessed correctly, that's what causes the "blurry effect"). Not working much with vid cams, I cannot give closer advice – but hopefully these hints help you a little.

Comment: An app that automatically creates files will be perfect too (assuming it won't lose video while switching). Any suggestions for that? I couldn't find anything except a hidden-cam app (I want to see what I'm recording).

Comment: As written, I do not work much with that, so I cannot give examples (besides, app recommendations are off topic here).